Could a lawyer agree not to take any further cases against a company?
The book Radium Girls tells a true story that happened about 100 years ago. At one point in the book, a lawyer is representing about five victims (former employees) who are suing the US Radium Corporation for poisoning them. USRC offers a settlement, which includes a stipulation that the lawyer in the case must sign an agreement to not take up any additional cases against USRC (from anyone) or to provide any kind of assistance to any similar cases, ever again. The lawyer agrees to the settlement because he believes that the victims will not live long enough to take the case to trial.
This seems to me to be a ridiculous thing to ask a lawyer to agree to. If a lawyer can just agree to never represent anyone against a company, couldn’t the company just bribe every lawyer in town to sign a similar agreement, effectively making them above the law?
Was this really legal 100 years ago? Would it still be legal now?
If it matters, the book takes place mainly in New Jersey.

It is relevant that the lawyer has "inside" information. They know the company will be willing to settle and have the evidence that makes them willing to settle. It therefore makes sense for the company to bury not only the case but all participants in an nda. And that necessarily also includes the lawyer not using the information for further cases. Therefore, whether legal or not, there is some logic to the case.

The rules prevent lawyers from accepting assignments which "are materially adverse to the interests of the former client unless the former client gives informed consent". No contract necessary (but the client can, I assume, preemptively document their disssent).

In most of the United States, it would be illegal for the lawyer to offer or accept this deal. Under Model Rule of Professional Conduct 5.6:

A lawyer shall not participate in offering or making:
(a) a partnership, shareholders, operating, employment, or other similar type of agreement that restricts the right of a lawyer to practice after termination of the relationship, except an agreement concerning benefits upon retirement; or
(b) an agreement in which a restriction on the lawyer's right to practice is part of the settlement of a client controversy.

The comments to the rule make clear that it "prohibits a lawyer from agreeing not to represent other persons in connection with settling a claim on behalf of a client."
I don't know what the law in New Jersey would have been at the time, but my guess is that the deal would have been legal, as my recollection is that Rule 5.6 was adopted to address cases like this.

Those rules are not laws, are they? "Violation of a Rule should not itself [...] create any presumption in such a case that a legal duty has been breached." "The Rules are designed to provide guidance to lawyers and to provide a structure for regulating conduct through disciplinary agencies." (Not through the courts.) The worst result would be disbarment, wouldn't it?

The model rules themselves are not laws, but they have been adopted in most states, and thus become laws. Penalties are typically limited to professional discipline.

Ah, interesting: The rules (the actually adopted ones) are more than just matters of a professional association.

Correct. And as adopted, I think they'll usually still include that language about presuming the breach of a duty, but that language is aimed at malpractice claims, rather than enforcement by disciplinary authorities.

@bdb484 The model rules have been adopted, at least partially, in all 50 states. California was the last holdout, but they gave in in 2018.

What if the company paid the layer a retainer for advice, so there would be a conflict of interest if they represented anyone against the company again?

It depends. If the lawyer still has clients adverse to the company, he would be prohibited from accepting that retainer. If he does not, he may still be barred from accepting that retainer under Rule 1.9.
